# multiple textfields various viewcontorllers only one testified data shown second automatically clears

Tags: ios, swift3, segue, textfield

I am using storyboards and preform segue and prepare for segue functions. Please watch the screen gif. If I enter one textfield value another one which is already entered shows nil.

- Visit this [gif image](https://media.giphy.com/media/13jWe2R65tiDrW/giphy.gif)
- Here is the source code:

**ViewController File**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet var trainNumberTextField : UITextField!
@IBOutlet var train2 : UITextField!

var stringVal : String!
var stringVal2 : String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    trainNumberTextField.delegate = self
    train2.delegate = self
    trainNumberTextField.tag = 1
    trainNumberTextField.text = stringVal
    train2.text = stringVal2
    train2.tag = 2
}

func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    if textField.tag == 1 {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "text2table", sender: self)
    }
    if textField.tag == 2 {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "text2table2", sender: self)
    }
    return false
   }
 }
```

**Second View Controller :**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let indexpath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow

    let currentcell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexpath!)!

    print(currentcell.textLabel!.text!)

    textOneValue = currentcell.textLabel!.text!
    let index = textOneValue.index(textOneValue.startIndex, offsetBy: 5)
     finalString =  textOneValue.substring(to: index)


    performSegue(withIdentifier: "table2text", sender: self)

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "table2text"{

    // =========== Destination view contorller name ===========
    let   viewcontorller = segue.destination as! ViewController

    viewcontorller.stringVal = finalString


    }
```

Comment: You should show some code, but I suspect you are segueing "forward" from your pick list to a new instance of the purple view controller each time. Read about unwind segues.

Comment: Please edit your question to include relevant code

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0kGSeBFpl-pSFphQ0NWVGhfYTg/view?usp=sharing Please check this link

Comment: Two textfields, when I tap on textfield one it get data from selected table cell from tableview one and please the value on textfield one. Similarly, when I tap on textfield two it go to tableview two and place the value on textfield two. But the main problem is when I selected textfield two, textfield one value is nil. https://media.giphy.com/media/13jWe2R65tiDrW/giphy.gif

Comment: Are you using an unwind segue? As I said, it sounds (and looks) like you are using a normal segue to a new instance of your view controller

Comment: check this link, in my pervious link file i tried unwind segues but I failed. Only one textfield is working when I working on unwind segues. This link my original code, using storyboard show type segues. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0kGSeBFpl-pdG1odkNGbmxuOUE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I hope you understand the problem I'm facing. Please go through the code and give some solution. I'm new to iOS.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can dismiss the viewController instead of segueing "Back" from your pick list to a new instance of the original view controller each time.
2. You can post value by closure or delegate. [Here is the code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7v-_GOglYPpeHRuaUI2bGZxaDQ/view?usp=sharing)